# CSS interferindo na posição do elemento ao arrastar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drag-n-drop

Tenho um script que permite clicar e arrastar um elemento pela tela e levá-lo até o rodapé da página, que tem uma área que atrai o elemento arrastado.

No topo da página há uma div com CSS:

```
width: 100%;
height: 55px;`.
```

E ela interfere completamente no funcionamento do script, movendo o elemento arrastado pra longe do mouse e atrapalhando a detecção do touchend no fundo da página.

A div não pode ser removida. Como faço pra compensar a posição do elemento que estou arrastando?

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 55px;"></div>
<div data-drag="0" class="thing">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="magnet-zone">
    <div class="magnet"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var magnet = document.querySelector('.magnet-zone');

function isOverlapping(el1, el2) {
    var rect1 = el1.getBoundingClientRect(),
        rect2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect();
    return !(rect1.top > rect2.bottom || rect1.right < rect2.left || rect1.bottom < rect2.top || rect1.left > rect2.right);
}

function moveToPos(x, y, here) {
    here.style.transform = 'translate(' + Math.round(x, 10) + 'px, ' + Math.round(y, 10) + 'px) translateZ(0)';
    here.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + Math.round(x, 10) + 'px, ' + Math.round(y, 10) + 'px) translateZ(0)';
}

function moveMagnet(x, y) {
    var dist = 12,
        width = $('body').width() / 2,
        height = $('body').height(),
        direction = x > width ? 1 : -1,
        percX = x > width ? (x - width) / width : -(width - x) / width,
        percY = Math.min(1, (height - y) / (height / 2));
    magnet.style.marginLeft = Math.round(dist / 1.5 * percX) + 'px';
    magnet.style.marginBottom = Math.round(dist * percY) + 'px';
}

function move(event) {
    var el = this,
        magnetRect = magnet.getBoundingClientRect(),
        elRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    x = this._posOrigin.x + event.pageX - this._touchOrigin.x;
    y = this._posOrigin.y + event.pageY - this._touchOrigin.y;
    moveMagnet(x + elRect.width / 2, y + elRect.height / 2);
    $('body').addClass('moving');
    var touchPos = {
        top: y,
        right: x + elRect.width,
        bottom: y + elRect.height,
        left: x
    };
    overlapping = !(touchPos.top > magnetRect.bottom || touchPos.right < magnetRect.left || touchPos.bottom < magnetRect.top || touchPos.left > magnetRect.right);
    if (overlapping) {
        var mx = magnetRect.width / 2 + magnetRect.left;
        var my = magnetRect.height / 2 + magnetRect.top;
        x = mx - elRect.width / 2;
        y = my - elRect.height / 2;
        if (!$(el).hasClass('overlap')) {
            $(el).addClass('transition');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(el).removeClass('transition');
            }, 150);

            setTimeout(function () {
                el.remove();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('body').removeClass('moving touching');
                }, 900);
            }, 1000);
        }
        magnet.className = magnet.className.replace(' overlap', '') + ' overlap';
        el.className = el.className.replace(' overlap', '') + ' overlap';
    } else {
        if ($(el).hasClass('transition')) {
            $(el).removeClass('transition');
        }
        if ($(el).hasClass('overlap')) {
            $(el).addClass('transition');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(el).removeClass('transition');
            }, 100);
        }
        magnet.className = magnet.className.replace(' overlap', '');
        el.className = el.className.replace(' overlap', '');
    }
    if (Math.round(x, 10) > 0 && Math.round(x, 10) < ($(window).width() - 40)) {
        moveToPos(x, y, this);
    } else {
        if (x < ($('body').width() / 2)) {
            var width = 0;
        } else {
            var width = ($(window).width() - 60);
        }

        moveToPos(width, y, this);
    }


};
$('[data-drag]')
    .on('touchstart mousedown', onTouchStart)
    .on('touchmove drag', move);

function onTouchStart(event) {
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    $('body').addClass('touching');
    $(this).removeClass('edge transition');
    this._touchOrigin = {
        x: event.pageX,
        y: event.pageY
    };
    this._posOrigin = {
        x: rect.left,
        y: rect.top
    };
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL0LLxh0/)

Answer (score 2):

A função `moveToPos` usa a função [`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform) do CSS pra mudar o objeto de lugar. O `translate` funciona como uma operação de matrizes, e portanto, relativa à posição inicial do objeto.

Ou seja, quando você usa `transform:  translate(10, 10)`, o objeto não vai se mover pra posição (10, 10) da página. Ele vai se mover 10px pra baixo e 10 px pra direita.

Os parâmetros calculados pra função `moveToPos` não levava a posição inicial do objeto em consideração, e calculava as novas coordenadas finais do objeto ao invés do quanto ele devia mover em relação à sua posição inicial.

No seu caso, a posição inicial do elemento era `y = 55px` por causa da `div`. Quando ele era arrastado 1px pra baixo, calculava que a posição final era `y = 56px`. Só que chamar `translate(0, 56)` vai mover o elemento 56px pra baixo e não 1. Era esse o problema.

As propriedades [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetLeft) e [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop) dão a posição do elemento e não mudam com a operação de `translate`, então você pode usá-las pra compensar o cálculo das coordenadas:

```
x = this._posOrigin.x + event.pageX - this._touchOrigin.x - this.offsetLeft; // Aqui
y = this._posOrigin.y + event.pageY - this._touchOrigin.y - this.offsetTop;  // E aqui
...
overlapping = !(elRect.top > magnetRect.bottom ||  elRect.right < magnetRect.left ||
                elRect.bottom < magnetRect.top ||  elRect.left > magnetRect.right);
if (overlapping) {
    var mx = magnetRect.width / 2 + magnetRect.left;
    var my = magnetRect.height / 2 + magnetRect.top;
    x = (mx - elRect.width / 2) - this.offsetLeft; // Aqui também pra dar snap no lugar certo
    y = (my - elRect.height / 2) - this.offsetTop; // Idem
```

Com isso também não há mais necessidade do `touchPos`. Ele pode ser substituido pelas propriedades do próprio elemento.

```js
var magnet = document.querySelector('.magnet-zone');

function isOverlapping(el1, el2) {
  var rect1 = el1.getBoundingClientRect(),
    rect2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect();
  return !(rect1.top > rect2.bottom || rect1.right < rect2.left || rect1.bottom < rect2.top || rect1.left > rect2.right);
}

function moveToPos(x, y, here) {
  here.style.transform = 'translate(' + Math.round(x, 10) + 'px, ' + Math.round(y, 10) + 'px) translateZ(0)';
  here.style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + Math.round(x, 10) + 'px, ' + Math.round(y, 10) + 'px) translateZ(0)';
}

function moveMagnet(x, y) {
  var dist = 12,
    width = $('body').width() / 2,
    height = $('body').height(),
    direction = x > width ? 1 : -1,
    percX = x > width ? (x - width) / width : -(width - x) / width,
    percY = Math.min(1, (height - y) / (height / 2));
  magnet.style.marginLeft = Math.round(dist / 1.5 * percX) + 'px';
  magnet.style.marginBottom = Math.round(dist * percY) + 'px';
}

function move(event) {
  var el = this,
    magnetRect = magnet.getBoundingClientRect(),
    elRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = this._posOrigin.x + event.pageX - this._touchOrigin.x - this.offsetLeft;
  y = this._posOrigin.y + event.pageY - this._touchOrigin.y - this.offsetTop;
  moveMagnet(x + elRect.width / 2, y + elRect.height / 2);
  $('body').addClass('moving');
  overlapping = !(elRect.top > magnetRect.bottom || elRect.right < magnetRect.left || elRect.bottom < magnetRect.top || elRect.left > magnetRect.right);
  if (overlapping) {
    var mx = magnetRect.width / 2 + magnetRect.left;
    var my = magnetRect.height / 2 + magnetRect.top;
    x = mx - (elRect.width / 2) - this.offsetLeft;
    y = my - (elRect.height / 2) - this.offsetTop;
    if (!$(el).hasClass('overlap')) {
      $(el).addClass('transition');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).removeClass('transition');
      }, 150);

      setTimeout(function() {
        el.remove();
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('body').removeClass('moving touching');
        }, 900);
      }, 1000);
    }
    magnet.className = magnet.className.replace(' overlap', '') + ' overlap';
    el.className = el.className.replace(' overlap', '') + ' overlap';
  } else {
    if ($(el).hasClass('transition')) {
      $(el).removeClass('transition');
    }
    if ($(el).hasClass('overlap')) {
      $(el).addClass('transition');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).removeClass('transition');
      }, 100);
    }
    magnet.className = magnet.className.replace(' overlap', '');
    el.className = el.className.replace(' overlap', '');
  }
  if (Math.round(x, 10) > 0 && Math.round(x, 10) < ($(window).width() - 40)) {
    moveToPos(x, y, this);
  } else {
    if (x < ($('body').width() / 2)) {
      var width = 0;
    } else {
      var width = ($(window).width() - 60);
    }

    moveToPos(width, y, this);
  }


};
$('[data-drag]')
  .on('touchstart mousedown', onTouchStart)
  .on('touchmove drag', move);

function onTouchStart(event) {
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  $('body').addClass('touching');
  $(this).removeClass('edge transition');
  this._touchOrigin = {
    x: event.pageX,
    y: event.pageY
  };
  this._posOrigin = {
    x: rect.left,
    y: rect.top
  };
}
```

```css
.thing,
.thing .circle,
.magnet {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.thing .circle,
.magnet-zone {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.explain {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* For some Androids */
}
.thing {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.thing .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #888;
  background-image: url(http://gravatar.com/avatar/84eac3a27d1acf0ef0d835d92c999b0d?s=80);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 50ms linear;
  transition: transform 50ms linear;
}
.thing.transition {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 150ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.145, 1.25);
  transition: transform 150ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.145, 1.25);
}
.thing.edge {
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.345, 1.1);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.345, 1.1);
}
.magnet-zone {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.145, 1.32);
  transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.145, 1.32);
}
.magnet-zone {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 100%) translateZ(0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%) translateZ(0);
}
.magnet-zone.overlap .magnet {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(0);
  transform: scale(1.1) translateZ(0);
}
.touching .circle {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) translateZ(0);
  transform: scale(0.9) translateZ(0);
}
.moving .magnet-zone {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0) translateZ(0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) translateZ(0);
}
.magnet-zone:after {
  content: '\00d7';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(0);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(0);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
}
.magnet {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.145, 1.15);
  transition: transform 200ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.145, 1.15);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) translateZ(0);
  transform: scale(0.8) translateZ(0);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threedubmedia.com/inc/js/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%;
height: 55px;"></div>


<div data-drag="0" class="thing">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="magnet-zone">
  <div class="magnet"></div>
</div>
```